# Finding the latest build version of Library

Tags: github, gradle

I think I am missing something, but I want to add library from github to Android, I don't see anywhere on the Github page the latest built version of the library so I can include it in my gradle file. I have to go to maven or jetpack manually and search for it. Is there a shortcut? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using android studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Lint check which allow Android Studio to query the latest versions available.

First you will have to activate this Lint Check

Go to `Settings`, then `Editor` > `Inspections` and search for `Newer Library Version Available` and **check it**.

[image: Lint check]

Then run a code Analyze with `Analyze` > `Run Inspection by Name...` and type `newer` and select `Newer Library Version Available`

[image: Newer Library]

Run the inspection on the wanted scope (module only, full project, etc...)

Then you will see which library has a new version available.

[image]

**PS**

As stated by the Lint description of this feature, **you should not let this check activated** because it may **slow your code analysis** (query the repositories can take time)

Comment: Iaccepted it although it does not fully answer the question. I really want to know the version from github before doing any android studeio integration

Comment: @Snake I think I misunderstood your situation. Did you clone the GitHub repository and use it as a module into your project?

Comment: I am actually using it in gradle in android studio but I just want to know what's the current library version without having android studio to do the work for me. I was wonder if people usually obtain the last version by some manual way without letting android studio tell them the recent version

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `+` annotation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_resolution) to get a dynamic version. It can be use for the major, minor and patch part of the version. Ex :

```
// Major
compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '+'

// Minor
compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.+'

// Patch
compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.18.+'
```

But [it's not a good practice](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/) to use such a dependency resolution.

> - Dependencies can unexpectedly introduce behavior changes to your app. Read your changelogs carefully!
> - The same source built on two different machines can differ. How many times have you said "but it works on my machine?"
> - Similarly, builds built on the same machine but at different times can differ. I've wasted so much time on builds that worked one minute
>     then broke the next.
> - Past builds cannot be reproduced perfectly. This makes it difficult to revert safely.
> - There are security implications if a bad actor introduces a malicious version of a dependency.

Comment: Exactly,  I am trying to avoid the +. But how  do  I know what is the latest or current stable version? In case of Mockito, how did you know that version 2.x exists? I cant find this info on the github page!

Comment: I updated my answer with `mockito-core`, on the github page you can find the last stable version https://github.com/mockito/mockito. You also can browse the maven repository https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core. I personally do both.